# External IP not exposed Helm Dask

Tags: kubernetes

I had this working at one time, now it doesn't work anymore. 
What I'm trying to do is create a `dask cluster` on `microk8s kubernetes`. 
According to the `Helm` website: `https://hub.helm.sh/charts/dask/dask`, to deploy the cluster I must type in the following:

```
helm repo add dask https://helm.dask.org/
helm repo update
helm install --name my-release dask/dask
```

However, I performed a `microk8s kubectl get svc` I don't see an `external IP signed`:

```
NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
kubernetes          ClusterIP   10.152.183.1     <none>        443/TCP           40h
my-dask-jupyter     ClusterIP   10.152.183.219   <none>        80/TCP            12m
my-dask-scheduler   ClusterIP   10.152.183.89    <none>        8786/TCP,80/TCP   12m
```

When I performed a the following I get a `null` value:

```
  echo http://$DASK_SCHEDULER_UI_IP:$DASK_SCHEDULER_UI_PORT     -- Dask dashboard
  echo http://$JUPYTER_NOTEBOOK_IP:$JUPYTER_NOTEBOOK_PORT       -- Jupyter notebook
```

Please help, I think there may be some setup I need to perform with microk8s?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at dash helm-chart repo on github you can find this commit:
[Make ClusterIP the default service type](https://github.com/dask/helm-chart/commit/9f9aa245cf686363b517c9013eb9b3488e46fab0).

It looks like ClusterIP is now the default.

If you want to overwrite it use `--set` e.g.:

```
helm install --name my-release dask/dask --set scheduler.serviceType=LoadBalancer
```

or clone the repo from github and change default values in values.yaml file